# Ограничение ресурсов сервера в PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, господа.

Есть небольшое приложение, и проблема в ресурсозатратности. Дело в том, что если его будут использовать более, чем n человек одновременно - оно будет некорректно работать, в связи с этим появился вопрос: как контролировать расход ресурсов с помощью PHP, а не настроек сервера?

К примеру, чтобы можно было тратить n ресурсов. На данный момент вижу лишь следующий вариант:

При старте работы приложения в конфигурационный файл записывать +1, и в конце работы -1. И при достижении, допустим, 10 запусков одновременно пользователю не давать запустить приложения, сообщая об очереди.

Comment: У вас приложение каждую секунду сервер запрашивает что ли? Или скрипты запускается на сервере с установкой `set_time_limit(0);`?

Comment: каждая такая попытка писать +1 и -1 в конечном счете упирается в то "как узнать, что пользователь" закончил работу. Так что ход мысли верный, надо считать сколько активных пользователей, другой вопрос как именно это делать. Но вообще интересно, что у вас там такое сервер делает трудозатратное.

Answer (score 1):

Например, у вас есть демон, который отсылает огромное количество запросов на какие-то внешние ресурсы и записывает результаты в базу. Предположим, работа такого демона длится от 1 минуты до 20 минут. А вызывается он в кроне каждую минуту. Как сделать так чтобы в один момент времени работал только один демон ?

Чтобы не возникало таких ситуаций, когда одно и тоже сообщение отправляется по несколько раз, нужно хранить где-то состояние демона, запущен ли он в данный момент времени или нет (в бд, в файлах). Каждый раз перед запуском демона нужно проверять, запущен ли он, если да, то не запускать.

Теперь частности.

Если делаем через базу: то таблица demons выглядит из 3 колонок: название демона(name), кол-во запущенных демонов(runnig_count), максимальное кол-во одновременно запущенных демонов(max_count). Проверяем, если runnig_count < max_count - запускаем демон, увеличиваем max_count на 1. Демон завершился - max_count уменьшаем на 1

Если делаем через файловую систему: тут поможет функция [flock](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.flock.php). т.е. на каждый отдельный запуск демона создается свой lock файл.

```
class Lock
{
    private static $_LockHandle;

    public static function lockfile($lockName) {

        self::$_LockHandle = fopen('/tmp/'.$lockName.'.lock', 'w+');
        if (!flock(self::$_LockHandle, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
            return False;
        }

        return True;
    }

    public static function unlock() {
        if(is_resource(self::$_LockHandle)) {
            fclose(self::$_LockHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и логика работы по такой же схеме как и с базой

```
$lockName = 'DemonName';
$max = 10;
$demonCounter = 0;
$isDemonExecute = False;

while ($demonCounter < $max) {
    $lockFileName = $lockName.$demonCounter;
    if (Lock::lockfile($lockFileName)) {
        // Делаем что нужно
        Lock::unlock($lockFileName)
        $isDemonExecute = True;
        break;
    }
    $demonCounter++;
}

if ($isDemonExecute) {
    // Сообщение о успешной работе
} else {
    // Сообщение о нагрузке, попробуйте позже
}
```